# Assertion Error occurred while running HTML5 audio creating program in Hackerrank

Tags: html, css, syntax

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
  <title>Destiny</title>
  <link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 // write your code
 <p>regular player</p>
<audio controls>    
   <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   <source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
   <source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">

</audio>   

</body>
</html>
```

while running this Program in hackerrank the below error occurred

```
self = <test_webpage.TestWebpage object at 0x7f078f22f0f0>

        def test_indexpage(self):
    
            site = self._index.find_all('audio')
    
            count = 0
    
            for audio in site:
    
                count +=1
    
    >       assert count==3
    
    E       assert 1 == 3
    
    test/test_webpage.py:19: AssertionError
```

I couldn't find out the error and also I have written the correct syntax for creating audioPlayer using HTML5

Please anyone familiar with HTML5 Multimedia please give me the solution

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.
Try this code. It worked for me.

```
<body>
 // write your code
<audio controls>    
   <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>   
<audio preload='none'>    
   <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>  
<audio loop>    
   <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its correct solution for HTML5 audio question

```html
<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <audio controls preload="none">
        <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <audio controls loop>
        <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only help on this.

assert count==3

E assert 1 == 3
i can make this  assert 2 ==3.

Use

```
<audio controls>    
   <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   <source src="audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
   <source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
 Your browser does not support <audio > tag.
</audio>
```

May be from this you will get some idea. I couldn't go further.

Answer (score 0):

In hakerrank we need to start the server to run html program
If we start the test without starting the server it will show assertion error like this
U can start the server by opening terminal and type npm start

Answer (score 0):

Before running the test case this Run the program normally and let the server connect.

```
<p>regular player</p>
<audio controls>
   <source src="SampleAudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
   <source src="SampleAudio.wav" type="audio/wav">
   <source src="SampleAudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: What is the difference with the question ? It's the same no-working code. Please [edit] your answer to more explain

Comment: it is nothing to do with the code, it is an error of the server of hacker-rank platform.

Answer (score -1):

In your source tag, please specify the name and location of audio file properly. As in case of hackerrank, please look through sidebar in IDE it will be just below your index.html file. I guess, it would be SampleAudio.mp3.
Well in that case, the tag becomes -

source src="SampleAudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"

and one thing, instead of using it 3 times use it once.

Comment: Definitely it will work, please check the file name first then let me know. If not then it would be sampleAudio.mp3

Comment: I have tried everything but this error not getting resolve.